# Option Strict ON made some errors

Tags: vb.net, option-strict

I had to enable Option Script, in order to use properly OpenXML package. Once I've done, I had several errors, regarding implicit conversions from a type to another.

```
Label6.Text = FormatNumber(CInt(Form3.Label12.Text), "0.00") 'O.S. On disallows implicit conversions from String to Integer'

hrrspk.Add(Form3.ListBox2.Items(i)) 'O.S. On disallows implicit conversions from Double to Integer'

tsdom.Add(((hrrspk(ts) - CInt(Label6.Text)) * (CInt(Label3.Text) - CInt(Label4.Text)) / (CInt(Label6.Text))) + CInt(Label4.Text)) 'O.S. On disallows implicit conversions from Double to Integer'

hrrnativexcel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION") 'O.S. On disallows implicit conversions from Object to Application'

hrrnativexcel.Cells(1, 1).value = "Time [s]" 'O.S. On disallows late binding'

For Each o As String In Form3.ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Zip(Form3.ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of Object), Function(x1, x2) x1 & "," & x2) 'O.S. On prohibits operands of type Object for operator &.'
```

How could I change this line in order to resolve this errors? Thanks all are gonna answer me.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8 and see if you can work it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Label6.Text = FormatNumber(CInt(Form3.Label12.Text), "0.00") - O.S
```

To:

```
Label6.Text = CDbl(Form3.Label12.Text).ToString("0.00")
```

For the Double to Integer error.

Change:

```
hrrspk.Add(Form3.ListBox2.Items(i))
```

To:

```
hrrspk.Add(CInt(Form3.ListBox2.Items(i)))
```

Change:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text.Split(".")(1).Length < 3 Then
```

To:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text.Split(".".ToCharArray())(1).Length < 3 Then
```

For the Object and & one, change:

```
Function(x1, x2) x1 & "," & x2
```

To:

```
Function(x1, x2) CStr(x1) & "," & CStr(x2) ' or use x1.ToString() and x2.ToString()
```

Comment: He's just comment "O S" meaning "option strict". It isn't actually part of the code I don't think.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer  Haha!  You just might be right...   =)

Comment: Yes, it's how @AndrewMortimer writes. Sorry for writing wrong, now I edited the post.

Comment: I'm correcting the line I'm able to. Could you help me to correct the error about conversion from String to Char and from Double to Integer?

Comment: This is the line with the string to char error: 'If Me.TextBox1.Text.Split(".")(1).Length < 3 Then'

Comment: That line didn't even make it into your original post, but I'll put a solution in for that one.

Comment: Thanks for the line I missed. I'm correcting my code step by step. Btw, at the moment I still haven't found any final solution for late binding issue. What I did is to reach the compiler settings (where I enabled Option Strict) and I set Late Binding alerts from error to warning, in order to have the notification of the problem and at the same time debugging my application. I tried to run the part where the Excel Interop is programmed and seems to run, even with Option Strict turned on. Maybe I'll change my code when I'll find a final solution...

Comment: You probably have `hrrnativexcel` declared as `Object`?  If that is the main excel reference, change it to `Excel.Application` instead of `Object`.  For variables referring to Sheets, use `Excel.WorkSheet`, for Workbooks use `Excel.Workbook`.

Comment: That's the strange thing, because I've found online the same you're saying me, but hrrnativexcel has always been declared as Excel.Application. Nevertheless I'm having back this error, so I changed Late Binding option in order to solve temporarily.

Comment: @telemaco10399 It's possible you'll have some things that require late binding.  If so, the best way to do it is to separate it out into a separate routine that you can put in a file that doesn't have `Option Strict On`.